# Appium Cannot get the element as the element ID will vary from time to time

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

I am using Appium to scrapy some data from an app,

the element xpath is android.view.View[@content-desc="25"]
but what i want to get is the value "25".
[image]
For example, the time its shows is 11:25
in Appium , it shows me that
el1 = driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, value="25")

However i cannot find this element as it varies from time to time .

Comment: Does the parent element have consistent properties?

Comment: You can use xpath if the parent element is consistent to get the corresponding child value, which is the same query posted to you by @Raju as above!

Comment: @Raju How can i check which one are the parent element?

Comment: @BipinKumarChaurasia can you elaborate more how to use child value ?

Comment: http://web.simmons.edu/~grabiner/comm244/weekfour/document-tree.html#:~:text=Parent%20and%20Child,element%20in%20the%20document%20tree. has the information on parent-child elements. https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html has information on how to handle them in xpath.